# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined with a offset

Tags: javascript

I found a lot of issues on stackoverflow but it is not working for me.
This is my code according to this error:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    // Remove the # from the hash, as different browsers may or may not include it
    //console.log('load function');
    var hash = location.hash.replace('%23','#');

    if(hash != ''){

       // Clear the hash in the URL
       // location.hash = '';   // delete front "//" if you want to change the address bar

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#calculator-pricing').offset().top - 85}, 10);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: That element's `.offset()` is returning null. Do you have sample HTML?

Comment: Does `$('#calculator-pricing')` actually find anything? It's worth checking that it gives you an element back.

Comment: have you try `$('#calculator-pricing').offsetTop` ?

Comment: it is working with offsetTop! thank you